# How to remove Text in the center of a Cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I am going around this the long way but what I am trying to do is extract the text in the center of a cell with text on both sides of it.

Example Text is:

```
Alliance: CRAZY CATS (Neutral)
Alliance: Dark Arts (Yours)
Alliance: Portal (Hostile)
```

I want to extract everything between `:` and `(`

In these cases I only need the name of the alliance the person is in. I tried to do a regedit but didn't completely understand it. I tried a few different formulas but was only able to remove either the first part or the last part and I could push them to two different cells but couldn't get them to work together in the same cell.

Comment: If you've tried something, make sure to document it in your question. Otherwise, it'll attract negative feedback from users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use REGEX functions, but I find that not everyone understands them. So here, I'll supply a non-REGEX solution.

Supposing your sample data were in A2:A4 (with some header in A1), place the following in B2 (or row 2 of any other column):

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="","",TRIM(MID(A2:A,FIND(":",A2:A)+1,FIND("(",A2:A)-FIND(":",A2:A)-1))))
```

Comment: This works PERFECTLY thank you so much... I tried something close to this and I could remove text off the end or the front but not both at the same time... You are awesome thank you....

Comment: Glad to help, JoeJoe. If you would, please take a minute to mark one of the answers as "Best Answer." It doesn't matter which to me. It just helps future contributors here to see at a glance that this issue is resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, ":\s*([^(]+)\s*\(")
```

- `:` literal ":"
- `\s*` zero or more `s`pace characters
- `()` capture group
- `[^(]+` one or more of  any character except `(`
- `\(` literal `(`

See

- [What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)
- [Tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)